# Is it possible to only use C syntax in a .mm file?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

Is it possible to only use C syntax in a .mm file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with writing .mm file that works in terms of plain old functions, strings and arrays, rather than the additions made by objective-c and c++.

However, there are a few cases where valid C isn't valid C++ (or Objective-C++) which you'll want to consider (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/big-picture.html#faq-6.11).

Also, if you're using Objective-C++ files in the same project as Objective-C, then you need to be careful not to include any C++-only stuff in headers you reference from vanilla Objective-C files. You'll also need to make sure that you export any C-style functions defined in a .mm propertly if you want to use them in a .m (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.6).

Comment: +1 for the first sentence, -1 for the second. Ever tried compiling a large-ish C code base with a C++ compiler ?

Comment: There exists a common subset of C and C++, but it's very common that idiomatic C code is not legal C++ code...